# MySQL join two tables using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `menudetails` and `meals`. The `menudetails` table looks like:

```
id | menu_id | meal_id |
1  |    9    |   15    |
2  |    9    |   16    |
```

and the `meals` table looks like:

```
meal_id |   name    | 
   15   | hamburger |  
   16   | pizza     |
```

I have `$menu_id=9`. I want all meals `name` and `meal_id` whose `menu_id=9`. I tried:

```
$query = "SELECT meals.meal_id, meals.name".
         "FROM menudetails, meals ".
         "WHEREmenudetails.menu_id = '$menu_id'";
```

but didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got any error or not getting expected output?

Comment: thanks, I've got the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` those tables and use proper white spaces too. Try this:

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM meals ml JOIN
     menudetails md on md.meal_id=ml.meal_id
WHERE md.menu_id='$menu_id'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT ml.meal_id, ml.name
FROM menudetails md, meals ml
WHERE md.meal_id=ml.meal_id
  AND md.menu_id = '$menu_id'
```

**Analysis:**

With your code, we will get a query like:

```
SELECT meals.meal_id, meals.nameFROM menudetails, meals WHEREmenudetails.menu_id = '$menu_id'
```

So, use proper whitespaces in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT meals.meal_id,
       meals.name
FROM meals
INNER JOIN menudetails ON menudetails.meal_id=meals.meal_id
WHERE menudetails.menu_id = 9
```